# In C: having trouble with header files and compiling the main function

Tags: c, header

[This is the main code, and I have no trouble with the header file, but when I compile it, I get this error: error: expected ‘;’, identifier or ‘(’ before ‘int’

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "class_info.h"
int main(void)
{
int i, num, gradenum, gradetot;
struct student s;
printf("How many students are in your class?");
scanf("%d",&num);
gradetot = 0;
for (i = 0; i<=num; i++)
{
    printf("Enter last name: ");
    scanf("%s", &s.last_name);      
    printf("Enter student id: ");
    scanf("%d", &s.student_id);
    printf("Enter grade: \n");
    scanf(" %c", &s.grade);
    if (s.grade = 'A')
    {
        gradenum = 4;
    }
    else if (s.grade = 'B')
    {
        gradenum= 3;
    }
    else if (s.grade = 'C')
    {
        gradenum = 2;
    }
    else if (s.grade = 'D')
    {
        gradenum = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        gradenum = 0;
    }
    gradetot = gradenum+gradetot;
}
printf("Total grade point average: ",gradetot/num);
}
```

This is the class_info.h file:

```
#define CLASS_SIZE 100
struct student{
char *last_name;
int student_id;
char grade;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and include your code in a code block. Image files of code are considered [especially] bad on SO. Also, include a separate code block for `class_info.h` as the error could easily be in that.

Comment: If you want someone to give some of their own time in order to help you, you should at least try to make it easier.  Images of code can't be cut-and-pasted to a local machine for testing, for example.

Comment: I have updated this post if anyone is still willing to help. Sorry, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten a semicolon after '}' in .h file. Sorry for my previous answer. It was definitly not good :).

```
#define CLASS_SIZE 100
struct student{
    char *last_name;
    int student_id;
    char grade;
};
```